# Delete Value in AsyncStorage React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a function for looking item exists or not.

```
addNewPerson(name) {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('savedPersons', (err, result) => {
        const name = [name];
            if (result !== null) {
                var newIds = JSON.parse(result).concat(name);
                AsyncStorage.setItem('savedPersons', JSON.stringify(newIds));
                console.log('Data Found', result);
            } else {
                AsyncStorage.setItem('savedPersons', JSON.stringify(name));
                console.log('Data Added', name);
            }
    });
}
```

Now I want to delete some specific person in "savedPersons".

I Tried this code:

```
AsyncStorage.removeItem('savedPersons','Uzuner');
```

error text is : "callback is not a function."

How can I delete item in asycnStorage's array?

**Solved:**

I write this code for deleting item.

```
removePost = async (post_id) => {
  try {
    const posts = await AsyncStorage.getItem('savedPersons');
    let postsFav = JSON.parse(posts);
    const postsItems = postsFav.filter(function(e){ return e !== post_id });

    // updating 'posts' with the updated 'postsItems'
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('savedPersons', JSON.stringify(postsItems));

  } catch(error) {
    console.log('error: ', error);
  }};
```

Thanks alot all users for replies.

Comment: 1. load the string from storage and parse it into array 2. remove person from array 3. save stringified array to storage

Comment: thank you. I will try this. Do you have any example code?

Answer (score 1):

AsyncStorage.removeItem is an asynchronous task which returns a promise or callback. Also, if you want to remove an element from the array then you need to get the array first,delete the element and push it back to the local storage. Something like this,

```
AsyncStorage.getItem("savedPersons")
.then(persons =>{
const index = persons.indexOf("Uzuner");
const modifiedPersons = persons.splice(index,1); 
AsyncStorage.setItem("savedPersons",modifiedPersons)
.then(() => console.log(done))
.catch((error) => console.log("error")); 
})
.catch(error => console.log("Error while retrieving the savePersons"));
```